# EXCEL VBA MACRO FORMATAR COR FONTE TEXTO APÓS "PONTO"

Tags: vba

Boa tarde!
Preciso formatar texto em vermelho após um ponto nas células do Range ("A2:A200") e algumas células poderão ou não ter esse ponto.

Obrigado!

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Veja também [ask] e visite a nossa [help].

Comment: Consulte a [help] para entender que tipo de pergunta é esperada aqui. Mesmo assim, você pode tentar resolver, e ao esbarrar em um problema claro e objetivo, pode [edit] a pergunta e fornecer um [mcve] do seu problema e uma descrição da dificuldade. Ao editar, a postagem automaticamente entra numa reavaliação e pode ser reaberta pela comunidade se ficar adequada para o site.

Comment: Considerando que orientações e links relevantes já foram passados, o espaço de comentários foi desativado e informações impertinentes removidas para otimizar o tempo da comunidade. Fica sugestão de uma boa lida na documentação em questão para que eventuais novas interações sejam mais produtivas.